# Ruby on Rails Override a method that expects a block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, overriding, codeblocks

With the new attribute marked_deleted in AssistantTeacher class,
We want all queries to work  with the basic assumption of only selection where marked_deleted attribute is false.

This is easy (using squeel query language instead of standard AR query language)

```
class AssistantTeacher < ActiveRecord.Base
    # Gives a default query which always includes the condition here
    default_scope  {where{marked_deleted == false }}
end
```

This means that queries like *AssistantTeacher.all* will actually be

```
AssistantTeacher.all.where{marked_deleted == false}
```

Works great.
Likewise AssistantTeacher.find_each() also works with the limitation.
likewise

```
AssistantTeacher.where{atcode == "MPL"}
```

also executes as

```
I
```

However then the tricky part:
We need to reverse the default_scope for admins etc in special cases:

```
class AssistantTeacher < ActiveRecord.Base
  # Gives a default query which always includes the condition here
  default_scope  {where{marked_deleted == false }}
  # If a query is unscoped then the default_scope limitation does not apply
  # scoped is the default scope when there is no default_scope
  unscoped { scoped}
end
```

This works fine for

```
def self.all_including_marked_deleted
    return unscoped{all} 
end
```

However: the question
I can't figure out how to do an unscoped for  an admin version of find_each with a block

```
def self.find_each_including_marked_deleted &block
    return unscoped{find_each(block)} 
end
```

DOESNOT work. Nor do any other combination with block that I can think of.

Anyone any ideas what I can do to get my overriding method find_each_including_marked_deleted to pass its block to the unscoped call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a small syntax problem. If you add a `&` to the front of your `block`, you should be fine:

```
def self.find_each_including_marked_deleted &block
    unscoped { find_each &block } 
end
```

What's going on here? Inside the method body, the `block` variable is an instance of `Proc` (that's what the `&` is doing in front of the `block` param). You can verify this by checking `block.class`. `find_each` takes a block, not a proc, so you need the `&` to convert the proc back to a block.

Clear as mud? You can [read more about it here](http://weblog.raganwald.com/2008/06/what-does-do-when-used-as-unary.html).